# Как закачать документы на GoogleDrive в формате GoogleDocs?

Tags: php, json, post, google-drive

Здравствуйте. Появилась необходимость написать следующий скрипт: файл Word закачивается в GoogleDrive, мы получаем его id и через file_export даем ссылку на скачивание PDF файла. Вначале пытался напрямую закачивать файл на GoogleDrive. Он туда загружался, но потом его нельзя было экспортировать в PDF. Однако для экспорта нам нужно иметь файл в формате GoogleDocs с MimeType "application/vnd.google-apps.document".

После долгих гуглений нашел следующую [ссылку](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads#importing_to_google_docs_types_wzxhzdk8wzxhzdk9), но использовав код из нее я не получил желаемого результата.

Также прочитал в одном месте, что можно передать параметр convert: TRUE в запросе в GoogleDrive и он сам его попробует конвертировать в свои форматы.

Как правильно построить запрос в GoogleDrive чтобы добиться успеха?

Comment: Если нужно просто преобразовать doc/docx в pdf, можно использовать PHPWord. https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord

Answer (score 0):

> Вначале пытался напрямую закачивать файл на GoogleDrive. Он туда загружался, но потом его нельзя было экспортировать в PDF.

Предположим, Вы загрузили файл на Google Drive в формате **docx** и можете открыть его сами для редактирования по ссылке вида `https://docs.google.com/document/d/<идентификатор файла>/edit`. Тогда Вам же будет доступна и ссылка для скачивания его в формате PDF - `https://docs.google.com/document/d/<идентификатор файла>/export?format=pdf` (отличие только после идентификатора файла).

Чтобы этой ссылкой стало возможно пользоваться и другим людям, надо изменить разрешения для файла - открыть им доступ на чтение. Проще всего можно этого добиться, переместив сам файл в соответствующую (специально созданную, если ее не было)  папку с требуемым разрешением на уровне папки. Тогда анонимные пользователи также смогут скачать  PDF версию загруженного Вами файла.